# Maintaining kernel modules submitted in the Software Center over kernel updates

Tags: kernel, software-center, application-development

This question is specifically for submitting a package in the Software Center.

If I wish to submit a package that contains a kernel module (*.ko) which will install in /lib/modules/ and there is a kernel update with a new patch level number, i.e. 3.2.0-, how will my package's module be handled as it will not be installed in the new /lib/modules/?

Is this something that I have to maintain myself maybe via a startup script/check and manually copy/install the *.ko file to the new kernel modules location?

Answer (score 0):

In general, kernel modules have to be built for the current kernel and not simply copied.

If you need a custom module, either file a bug report or consider building a custom kernel.

Comment: Well, this is my module that I had written and is needed by the application that accompanies it. I do agree, in most cases, on a kernel update, it should be rebuilt. Although the subsystem that this module resides in is rarely if at all touched in the majority of patch releases for a specific kernel tree.

Comment: Why not submit your module to kernel.org ? Probably better then a .deb

Comment: I have thought about it but they [kernel.org developers] work on a pretty fast and demanding pace, one that may be difficult for me to keep up with. Although it is worth another consideration.

Comment: Well, if your kernel module is as stable as you claim, the work should be minimal.